# error when using flextesa: mempool already contains a conflicting operation

Tags: testing

when using flextesa to run a test suite I often get this error:
Error while applying operation oojMmYYobT1pFJkVowfGUMKSfvaCBRfkGBxaxaHHkEw7YvrfDup:\nError:\n  The operation oojMmYYobT1pFJkVowfGUMKSfvaCBRfkGBxaxaHHkEw7YvrfDup cannot be added because the mempool already contains a conflicting operation that should not be replaced (e.g. an operation from the same manager with better fees)

what could be the cause? how can I adjust flextesa to not create this error situation?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a general problem people have with the tezos protocol: you seem to have an operation that is in the mempool, you can replace it with a higher-fee one or wait for it to be included or garbage-collected.